# Cómo cambiar el texto de un input en tiempo real?

Tags: javascript

***He leído que es con el evento keyup o keydown, pero no me funciona.. un ejemplo aca, que intenté realizar:***

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var d = document,
        prueba = d.getElementById("prueba");
    prueba.addEventListener("keypress", function(j) {
        var codigo = 'which' in j ? j.which : j.keyCode;
        var caracter = String.fromCharCode(codigo);
        var patronNumerico = /[0-9]/g;
        var patronLetra = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/gi;
        if (patronNumerico.test(caracter)) {
            console.log(caracter + "\n" + "es un número!");
            return true;
        } else if (patronLetra.test(caracter)) {
            console.log(caracter + "\n" + "es una letra!");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("Caracter no válido..");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="prueba"/>
```

*Lo que intento es que cuando escriban un **caracter** que no sea **ni letra ni numero**, simplemente **no** pueda escribirlo y en **tiempo real**, pero no lo bloquea, osea mi código **si identifica** que NO es una letra ni número pero no lo* **BLOQUEA**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza el metodo `event#preventDefault()` para que no acepte el caracter invalido  escrito.

En tu caso el objeto `event` seria el parametro `j`:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

 var d = document, prueba = d.getElementById("prueba");
 prueba.addEventListener("keypress",function(j){
   var codigo = 'which' in j ? j.which : j.keyCode;
   var caracter = String.fromCharCode(codigo);
   var patronNumerico = /[0-9]/g;
   var patronLetra = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/gi;
   if(patronNumerico.test(caracter)) {
    console.log(caracter + "\n" + "es un número!");
    return true;
   }
   else if(patronLetra.test(caracter)){
    console.log(caracter + "\n" + "es una letra!");
    return true;
   }
   else {

                // evitamos que se escriba la letra en el input
    j.preventDefault(); 
    return false; 
   }
 });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="prueba"/>
```

Comment: Junto con el return false, porque lo veo innecesario el return false, no?

Comment: Hace lo mismo que el metodo `preventDefault()` pero por convencion y compatibilidad se retorna `false`.